# XNA GIF Animation Library problem

Tags: animation, xna, gif

hey guys, i am trying to use the XNA　Gif Animation Library that i found online, then when i running , it keep givving me an exception said "The size of the data passed in is too large or too small for this resource." for GifAnimationContentTypeReader

```
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            SurfaceFormat format = (SurfaceFormat) input.ReadInt32();
            int width = input.ReadInt32();
            int height = input.ReadInt32();
            int numberLevels = input.ReadInt32();
            frames[i] = new Texture2D(graphicsDevice, width, height, false, format);
            for (int j = 0; j < numberLevels; j++)
            {
                int count = input.ReadInt32();
                byte[] data = input.ReadBytes(count);
                Rectangle? rect = null;
                frames[i].SetData<byte>(j, rect, data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
```

at this line "frames[i].SetData(j, rect, data, 0, data.Length);"
I donno how, but the data length is really huge though

Anyone know hows that happen
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of bytes (in your code: `count` and `data.Length`) should be equal to `width * height * bytesPerPixel`, where the `bytesPerPixel` depends on the data format (for the default `SurfaceFormat.Color` format it is 4).

If it is not equal, you don't have enough data (or have too much data) for the that texture.

You haven't provided enough detail in your question for me to be able to tell you *why* your the values are not equal.

Comment: it's so complicated for beginner like me, and i found out that using video will be much easier though take out more resources. Thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your code has bug.
Use this code:

```
namespace GifAnimation
{
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using System;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

public sealed class GifAnimationContentTypeReader : ContentTypeReader<GifAnimation>
{
    protected override GifAnimation Read(ContentReader input, GifAnimation existingInstance)
    {
        int num = input.ReadInt32();
        Texture2D[] frames = new Texture2D[num];
        IGraphicsDeviceService service = (IGraphicsDeviceService)input.ContentManager.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IGraphicsDeviceService));
        if (service == null)
        {
            throw new ContentLoadException();
        }
        GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice = service.GraphicsDevice;
        if (graphicsDevice == null)
        {
            throw new ContentLoadException();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        {
            SurfaceFormat format = (SurfaceFormat)input.ReadInt32();
            int width = input.ReadInt32();
            int height = input.ReadInt32();
            int numberLevels = input.ReadInt32();
            frames[i] = new Texture2D(graphicsDevice, width, height);
            for (int j = 0; j < numberLevels; j++)
            {
                int count = input.ReadInt32();
                byte[] data = input.ReadBytes(count);

                // Convert RGBA to BGRA
                for (int a = 0; a < data.Length; a += 4)
                {
                    byte tmp = data[a];
                    data[a] = data[a + 2];
                    data[a + 2] = tmp;
                }

                frames[i].SetData(data);
            }
        }
        input.Close();
        return GifAnimation.FromTextures(frames);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A little elaboration on the bug details wouldn't hurt anyone.